# In a exercise I need to find a retract $r:S^1 \cup[0,2] \times\{0\} \to S^1 \subset\mathbb R^2$.

Tags: algebraic-topology, retraction

Hi I am studying algebraic topology and I have trouble with finding retracts.
In a exercise I need to find a retract $r:S^1 \cup[0,2] \times\{0\} \to S^1 \subset\mathbb R^2$.
I had the following in mind:
$$r(x) = \frac{x}{\|x\|}$$
Here $S^1\subset \mathbb R^2$ is the unit circle.
But we run into trouble with the point $(0,0)\in S^1 \cup[0,2] \times\{0\} $. I have not been able to find a way to evade this problem point. Can someone help me or give me a hint on how to find the right retract?

Comment: Do you mean $r:S^1\cup[0,2]\times \{0\}\to S^1$?

Comment: Yes il edit that sorry!

Comment: Can you define the mapping without writing a single formula that works for all $x$?

Comment: Sorry @TedShifrin I don’t really understand what u mean.

Comment: I intuitively would think that sending the interval [0, 2] to the point (1,0) and all the other points unchanged would work, but I am not sure if that map is continuous then.

Comment: OK, so what you just said defines a function. Now you must prove the function is continuous. Get to work.

Comment: Alright! Thanks :)

Comment: Please do not delete a question immediately after receiving an answer.  This is disrespectful to the person who took the time to write an answer, and disrespectful to future askers who might find the answer helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a look at the function you have in mind: for any $x \in S^{1},$ $\lVert x \rVert$ is $1,$ so it's just the identity. Then, for any $x$ on the segment $[0, 2] \times \{0\}$ not equal to $(0, 0),$ we see that $\frac{x}{\lVert x \rVert}$ is just the point $(1, 0).$ Unfortunately, $\frac{x}{\lVert x \rVert}$ is not defined at $(0, 0).$

However, this gives us an idea of what our desired function should do: it should be the identity on $S^{1},$ and send all of $[0, 2] \times \{0\}$ to $(1, 0).$

So, let's define our function this way: let
$$r(x) = \begin{cases} \text{id}_{S^{1}} & \text{if} \; x \in S^{1} \\ (1, 0) & \text{if} \; x \in [0, 2] \times \{0\}.\end{cases}$$

We need to check this is well-defined: on the intersection $S^{1} \cap ([0, 2] \times \{0\}) = \{(1, 0)\},$ we see that $\text{id}_{S^{1}}$ and the constant function sending everything to $(1, 0)$ agree. So, we are good here.

Now, we need to show that this $r$ is continuous.

Note that $r|_{S^{1}}$ is the identity, hence is continuous. Similarly, $r|_{[0, 2] \times \{0\}}$ is the constant map sending everything to $(1, 0)$, hence is also continuous.

Finally, note that $S^{1}, [0, 2] \times \{0\}$ are two closed subspaces of $S^{1} \cup ([0, 2] \times \{0\}),$ whose union is the whole space. So, by the Pasting Lemma, $r(x)$ is continuous.

Since $r|_{S^{1}} = \text{id}_{S^{1}}$, $r$ is a retract to $S^{1}$, as desired.